# Why input never ends

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I have python 3.7 installed and I have this code:

```
print("Enter your name:")
x = input()
print("Hello, " + x)
```

I was writing the name and press enter but the input is not over, it is still running and waiting for more inputs

Edit:  the problem is that input is never ending, doesn't matter how many enters I press

Comment: Your code should work fine. How are you running it, in IDLE, in a bash terminal, etc?

Comment: Is that all of your code, or are you running this inside a loop?

Comment: I'm running it in Sublime Text 3, the problem is that input is never ending, doesn't matter how many enters I press

Comment: sublime doesnt support interactive things such as input......

Comment: it's not in a loop or any sort, if you submit one input, it should print it out once.

Comment: and more info about the how and why here.....https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/build-broken-python-3-input/44988

Answer (score 0):

Sublime text doesn't support inputting data. Read this : [Sublime text input not working](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/python-3-input-doesnt-work/34418)

That said, apparently [SublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) provides this sort of functionality, although I don’t use it myself so I don’t know much about it.